# Select multiple rows in Excel and read by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to implement the following Java program in Excel VBA.

[image]

The Java program has a data list with checkbox. I can select any rows by checking the checkboxes, then I click Show button, then the program opens a new window showing the detail statistics of the selected players.

Here is my Excel. I need some way to select rows or player names. I can select while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key but it is not as convenient as checkbox, at least my left hand has to touch keyboard.

[image]

I may add checkbox to each row. As the data have hundreds to thousands rows, vba runs very slow.

Do you have any ideas that how can I make an interface that allows user to select multiple rows conveniently?

Comment: Hi, did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as follows. For e.g. you need to toggle True/False values in a range **A1:A10** on a sheet. Then open the VBE window (Alt-F11) and go to the Sheet, right click, select the event for SelectionChange() and write the following code. It's fairly self explanatory:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
    Dim Intersection as Range
    Set Intersection = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")

    If Intersection Is Nothing Then
        ' Do nothing
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = Not (ActiveCell.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

That way in a single click, you will toggle the true-false value of a given cell. The rest of the code can then take over. The Range A1:A10 for a Table in Excel can be dynamically captured by using

```
TestBoundsRange = ListObject.ListColumns("ColumnName").DataBodyRange
```

Where you replace ListObject by the ListObject variable pointing to the correct Table.

Comment: This is a good idea. If I add checkbox, checkboxes cannot be filtered. Your method only requires single click. I would like to set font to Wingdings so that a character can present as a tick.

Comment: Yup, It's quite efficient (in terms of mouse movement) and can be used via just selecting using the keyboard too (moving in and out of the target zone for toggling).

Comment: Would appreciate an upvote if you think it'll work for you. Thanks :)